# JavaScript inside html document won't recognize html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm making a contact form for a website, I'm just modifying it to getting a dynamic table in it. I want the contents of the table to be sent with all the information of the email:

```html
<TABLE id="dataTable" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center"></th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Part</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Marca</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Referencia</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Producto</th>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TD style="text-align:center">
      <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" style="text-align:center" />
    </TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center"> 1 </TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center">
      <INPUT type="text" size="10" style="text-align:center" data-form-field="Marca" /> </TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center">
      <INPUT type="text" size="7" style="text-align:center" data-form-field="Ref" /> </TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center">
      <INPUT type="text" size="35" style="text-align:center" data-form-field="Prod" /> </TD>
  </TR>

</TABLE>
```

That's the table. I noticed that the tags with the "data-form-field" attribute are the ones that are sent in the email, so the first row always is being sent, but I made it a dynamic table so here is the table script for adding and deleting rows:

```html
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
  function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style = "text-align:center";
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name = "chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.style = "text-align:center";
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.style = "text-align:center";
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    element2.size = "10";
    element2.style = "text-align:center";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.style = "text-align:center";
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    element3.size = "7";
    element3.style = "text-align:center";
    cell4.appendChild(element3);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell5.style = "text-align:center";
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    element4.size = "35";
    element4.style = "text-align:center";
    cell5.appendChild(element4);

  }

  function deleteRow(tableID) {

    try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }

  }
</SCRIPT>
```

This one is inside my html document but I can't assign the attribute to the rows that are created with the script, it just won't recognize it.